# displaying array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a JavaScript array is the following manner:

```
var selectedColors= { 'Orange' : $("#Orange").val(),
                         'Light Blue' : $("#LightBlue").val(),
                         'Dark Red' : $("#DarkRed").val(),
                         'Dark Blue' : $("#DarkBlue").val()};
```

Then loop through each item to see which color was not selected, and then store them in another array:

```
var colorsNotSelected = [];
$.each(selectedColors, function (key, value) {
    if (value.length == 0)
        colorsNotSelected.push({key:key});
});
```

Here I want to display the colors not selected, but doing it the following way display the keys: 0,1,2,3 instead of Orange, Light Blue, Dark Red, Dark Blue.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
if (colorsNotSelected.length > 0)
    $.each(colorsNotSelected, function (key) { alert(key) });
    return false;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That is a Javascript Object, not a Javascript Array. FYI. Where is colorsNotSelected defined?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6sp8s/2/ <- Works fine as I see. Could you post what the value are

Comment: @KevinB miss type: added it above. selectedColors is a JS object, but why would that restrict me from accessing another array element?

Answer (score 1):

The object and array would iterate the same in jQuery. It appears you need to use braces to keep that return false statement under check:

```
if (colorsNotSelected.length > 0) {
    $.each(colorsNotSelected, function (key) { alert(key) });
    return false;
}
```

This is unnecessary:

```
colorsNotSelected.push({key:key});
```

Just do this:

```
colorsNotSelected.push(key);
```

This is also assuming somewhere above your example code you have this:

```
var colorsNotSelected = [];
```

Comment: Still dont see the color names. 0,1,2,3 is displayed. Also, yes There is var colorsNotSelected = []; in my code

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a for / in loop instead:

```
for(var i in colorsNotSelected){
   alert(i);
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use a `for...in` loop, use a `if (colorsNotSelected.hasOwnProperty(i))` check to avoid iterating through the object's native/inherent properties.